# Convergence of $\prod\limits_{t\in\mathbb{N}}P(|X_t|<\lambda^t)$, where $\lambda>1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\{X_t\}_{t\in\mathbb{N}}$ be an independent sequence of continuous random variables on the real line. Let $\lambda>1$. I am interested in the quantity
$$
P(\forall t\in\mathbb{N},\,|X_t| \le \lambda^t) = \prod_{t\in\mathbb{N}}P(|X_t|<\lambda^t),
$$
and specifically under what conditions it converges, that is, whether the product is nonzero.

The individual terms go to one, but they need to do this "fast enough" to ensure convergence. Can anyone give me some tips towards a solution or refer to literature that works with similar problems.

Comment: Intuitively,  I would have a look to the literature about 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theory

becauses for all $N$ : $P(\forall n=1\dots N, |X_n|\leq \lambda^n)\leq P(\sup_{n=1\dots N}|X_n|\leq \lambda^N)$

Comment: The product is nonzero iff every factor $P(|X_t|<\lambda^t)$ is nonzero and the series $\sum\limits_tP(|X_t|\geqslant\lambda^t)$ converges. Continuity of the distributions is offtopic. When the random variables $X_t$ are identically distributed, the convergence of the series is equivalent to the integrability of $(\log X)^+$.

Comment: @Did Thank you very much for your response. Do you by any chance know of a document that proves the last statement you made?

Comment: Here is a direct proof: one is considering $\sum\limits_nP(|X|\geqslant\lambda^t)=\sum\limits_nP(Z\geqslant zt)$ with $Z=\log|X|$ and $z=\log\lambda>0$. And one knows that the series in the RHS is approximately $E(Z)/z$.