# Proving a probability concerning a stationary ergodic stochastic process is nonzero.

Tags: probability-theory, ergodic-theory, stationary-processes

Let $\{X_t\}_{t\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a stationary ergodic sequence of continuous random variables with full support on the real line. Let $\lambda>1$ and $c>0$. I am interested in the probability
$$
P(\forall t\in\mathbb{N},\,|X_t| \le c\lambda^t),
$$
and specifically whether there are conditions to ensure that it is nonzero.

This is a generalisation of a [question I asked before.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1780635/convergence-of-prod-limits-t-in-mathbbnpx-t-lambdat-where-lambda) There I simplified the $\{X_t\}_{t\in\mathbb{N}}$ to be iid, in which case the condition $\mathbb{E}\log|X_t|<\infty$ turns out to be sufficient for the probability to be nonzero.

---

**Attempts:**

If the probability is zero for all $c>0$, then 
$$
\lim_{c\rightarrow\infty}P(\forall t\in\mathbb{N},\,|X_t| \le c\lambda^t) = 0,
$$
which is a contradiction, since this limit should be one. Therefore, once $c$ is sufficiently big, we know the probability is nonzero.

Next, I investigate the claim for any $c>0$. By the expectation condition one could get
$$
\sum_{t=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X_t>c\lambda^t) \approx \mathbb{E}\log|X_t| < \infty,
$$
so that by Borel-Cantelli $\mathbb{P}(\liminf\{\omega\in\Omega\mid |\epsilon_{k}| \le c\lambda^k\}) = 1$. Therefore there exists a random variable $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|\epsilon_{k}| \le c\lambda^k$ for all $k\ge N$ and thus we would have
$$
P(\forall t\in\mathbb{N},\,|X_t| \le c\lambda^t) = 
P(\forall t<N,\,|X_t| \le c\lambda^t).
$$
I'm not sure whether I am allowed to conclude that this last probability is nonzero.

Comment: "which is a contradiction, since this limit should be one" I wonder why this should be. What is the argument you have in mind? // To prove that the probability of the event of interest is positive for large enough $c$, note that the complement has probability at most $$\sum_tP(|X_t|>c\lambda^t)\leqslant\sum_tE(|X_t|)/(c\lambda^t)=E(|X_1|)/(c({}{}{}{}\lambda-1))$$ and that the RHS is $<1$ for every $c>E(|X_1|)/(\lambda-1)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. That is much cleaner than what I did myself. Don't you show that the limit is indeed one though, since $\lim_{c\rightarrow\infty}E(|X_1|)/(c(\lambda-1)) = 0$, assuming $E(|X_1|)<\infty$.

Comment: Yes the approach in my comment does show that the limit is $1$, but yours does not, afaict.